# Why does the Navigation Bar from the View still remain after Signing Out a User

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm working on a very simple app to try to wrap my mind around SwiftUI and Firebase. I have a Login View, a SignUp View, and the FirstView that gets presented once the user is logged in.

Once a User is logged in and the SignOut button is tapped, the Navigation Bar that was only visible in the FirstView, all of a sudden appears superimposed on the LoginView as well. That's not supposed to happen and I'm trying to understand why that happens. Perhaps I'm not dismissing the FirstView correctly?

As a side question, I'm also running into an issue where my User Data is presented/Updated on the FirstView after Signing In, but with a noticeable delay between the Text change for the fields within the view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the relevant code...

```
@main
struct AWSupportLoggerApp: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = AppViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
        }
    }
    
    
    
    class AppDelegate:NSObject,UIApplicationDelegate{
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
            FirebaseApp.configure()
            return true
        }
    }
    
    
}



    class AppViewModel: ObservableObject {
        private var db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        @Published var userInfo: User?
        @Published var signedIn: Bool = false
        
        var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
        let authRef = Auth.auth()
        
        var authHandle : AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
        var rootInfoCollection : CollectionReference!
        var userIdRef = ""
        
        
        
        func fetchUserData(){
            db.collection("Users").document("\(userIdRef)").getDocument { document, error in
                // Check for error
                if error == nil {
                    // Check that this document exists
                    if document != nil && document!.exists {
                        
                        self.userInfo = document.map { (documentSnapshot) -> User in
                            let data = documentSnapshot.data()
                            
                            let uid = data?["uid"] as? UUID ?? UUID()
                            let company = data?["company"] as? String ?? ""
                            let name = data?["name"] as? String ?? ""
                            let admin = data?["admin"] as? Bool ?? false
                            let photo = data?["photo"] as? String ?? ""
                            
                            return User(uid: uid, company: company, name: name, admin: admin, photo: photo)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        func listen(){
            handle = authRef.addStateDidChangeListener({ auth, user in
                print(user?.email ?? "No User Found")
                
                if let user = auth.currentUser {
                    self.userIdRef = user.uid
                    self.rootInfoCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("/Users/")
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.fetchUserData()
                    }
                    
                    self.signedIn = true
                    
                } else {
                    self.signedIn = false
                }
            })
            
        }
        
        func signIn(email: String, password: String){
            authRef.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
                guard result != nil, error == nil else {
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        
        func signOut(){
            do {
                try authRef.signOut()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        
        func signUp(email: String, password: String, company: String, name: String, admin: Bool, photo: String){
            authRef.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
                
                guard result != nil, error == nil else {
                    return
                }
                
                let db = Firestore.firestore()
                
                //Success
                db.collection("Users").document("\(result!.user.uid)").setData(["company" : "\(company)", "name" : "\(name)", "admin" : admin, "photo" : "\(photo)", "uid":result!.user.uid]) { error in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        
        func unbind() {
            if let handle = handle {
                authRef.removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
        
        var body: some View {
            
            NavigationView {
                if viewModel.signedIn {
                     FirstView()
                } else {
                    //.onAppear method is used for keyboard management (See Misc Functions...)
                    SignInView()
                        .onAppear(perform: UIApplication.shared.addTapGestureRecognizer)
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.listen()
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct FirstView: View {
        @EnvironmentObject private var appViewModel: AppViewModel
    
        var body: some View {
    
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                VStack(spacing: 50){
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Test")){
                        awButton(content: "Request Support", backColor: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.723585546, blue: 0.9907287955, alpha: 1)))
                            .shadow(color: Color.primary.opacity(0.5), radius: 20, x: 0, y: 20)
                            .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees:10), axis: (x: 10.0, y: 0, z: 0))
                    }
    
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Test")){
                        awButton(content: "Request Quote", backColor: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9372549057, green: 0.3490196168, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1)))
                            .shadow(color: Color.primary.opacity(0.5), radius: 20, x: 0, y: 20)
                            .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees:10), axis: (x: 10.0, y: 0, z: 0))
                    }
    
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Test")){
                        awButton(content: "Ticket Status", backColor: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4666666687, green: 0.7647058964, blue: 0.2666666806, alpha: 1)))
                            .shadow(color: Color.primary.opacity(0.5), radius: 20, x: 0, y: 20)
                            .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees:10), axis: (x: 10.0, y: 0, z: 0))
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationTitle(appViewModel.userInfo?.company ?? "Test")
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                appViewModel.signOut()
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Sign Out")
                }
            },trailing: HStack{
                Image(systemName: "bell")
                Text(appViewModel.userInfo?.name ?? "Tester")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to hide it explicitly, like

```
if viewModel.signedIn {
     FirstView()
        .navigationBarHidden(true)    // << here !!
} else {
```

Comment: This works when I hide the LoginView Nav Bar, but I still want to understand why it happens.

Comment: Because this works via view preferences, so it is set in login but not reset afterwards so remains in preference value. Using explicit modifier resets preferences so navigation view is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the navigationBar will cause lots of problems if you need it in other views .the better answer in my opinion is to

1 - create a splash view and set it as your starting view in @main file

2 - add a StateObject for tracking user loginState :

```
 class LoginState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLogin : Bool = false
}
```

3 - add navigationView to splash view

4 - pass loginState , StateObject as      .environmentObject(loginState) to navigationView

5- now you can change login state when ever you want from anywhere without need of hiding the navigation bar

Comment: Thank you Keyvan, but that's what I already have in place, and it works fine, but now the problem I'm trying to figure out is how to transition to my FirstView smoothly upon logging in and also how to update the User data on my FirstView when a new User logs in.